# Better to develop Ruby project on server or buy a faster desktop computer? B/c laptop too slow

Tags: linux, desktop-computer, development

I have a Linux laptop (Vostro V13) running a Celeron M chip. This is a fine laptop, but running unit tests especially for Rails applications is slow. I want a faster development environment but I don't want to spend too much money. So the choice I have is between $390 for a Linux desktop machine with a Pentium Dual Core Processor E5400 and just paying between $30 and $40 a month to Linode and trying to do development remotely on that server.

Can anyone with experience developing server applications using both methods offer any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a decent Internet connection then go for the remote machine. The costs for maintaining, powering, and cooling the new machine would take up a decent chunk of what you'd pay for the remote server. Plus, gio and kio let you operate on the remote machine pretty much the same as if it were local.

Comment: How much do you pay to cool your computers exactly?

Comment: i found a webpage about that:
http://michaelbluejay.com/electricity/computers.html